# Per-program, per-website bandwidth limiting software

Tags: windows, network-monitor, bandwidth

I would like a recommendation for a free or low cost Windows program that will monitor incoming bandwidth and choose where it would be used best, and mainly, allow me to throttle the connection to that program or site.

Windows version: 10
Main web browser: WaterFox (it's a 64-bit Firefox fork)

I found stuff like it (like NetLimiter and NetBalance), but I don't know if it would work with what I want to do.

Comment: NetLimter and NetBalance should probably be links.